# How do you handle timezones for data processing?

Tags: java, python, timezone, data-processing

curious how people have solved this problem...
I have a series of jobs that run overnight that roll up reports based on that day's data for customers. They're now asking for timezone support.

One of the reports is.. you had x number of orders last night, however last night could be different depending on timezone. What is the best way to organize or process the data so timezones are taking into account to make that job easier?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

It is good practice to represent all the dates in the UTC time zone. This timezone has no confusing daylight savings time. Then the customer in the US/Pacific timezone can ask for a report on orders between 2010-09-20T00:00-700 to 2010-09-21T00:00-700 (using [ISO 8601 format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)). The input layer of your program should convert both the customer dates and the stored order dates to seconds since the epoch in UTC and then go from there.

Comment: The data isn't pulled dynamically, it's run on nightly jobs. So if an order came in a 12:01 PST it would be processed on the next day's run.

Comment: Regardless of when the data is pulled your timezone behavior should be the same. Users enter dates with explicit timezones and the first thing that your code does is convert that to seconds since the epoch UTC. From then on it's all integers on the same timeline. Is that clear?

Answer (score 1):

In my app, I save the local time plus the offset to [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). This way, I can still compare the values (by converting them to universal time) in the code but when I display it on the screen, users will see the times they expect ("Yeah, I did that at 9:30 yesterday"). With a switch, they can show the timezone or switch to universal time or display all times in local time.

Comment: this would be for a terabyte of daily data that needs to be processed offline and rolled up into summary data.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with this, we've rolled the data up into hourly (or fifteen minute) buckets during the nightly run.  Then you can have the user requests grab the relevant buckets based on the time zone they are using for their report.